# Failed to load response data when updating data with file uploaded using laravel and inertiaJs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am building a SPA using Laravel 8 and inertiaJs

I am trying to update records that have a uploaded **file** (input file).
When storing data everything is good, but I have a problem when I try to **update** with file uploaded.

**PS**:
There is no error showing in the console or from the server. In network tab I see the message "Failed to load response", and like a result, the required fields show errors, it's like I sent an empty data.

see image : [Image showing the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpOAc.png)

This is my code:

**web.php**

```
Route::put('/software/{software}', [SoftwareController::class, 'update'])->name('software.update');
```

**SoftwareController**

```
 public function update(Request $request, Software $software)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'software_version' => 'nullable',
            'doc_ref' => 'nullable',
            'doc_version' => 'nullable',
            'doc_name' => 'required_with:doc_ref',
            'doc_filename' => 'nullable|file|mimes:docx,doc,xlsx,xls,pdf,jpg,png',
        ]);


        $doc_filename = $request->file('doc_filename') ? $request->file('doc_filename')->store('software/equipment', 'public') : null;
       
        $software->update(array_merge($data, ['doc_filename' => $doc_filename]));

        return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Software updated.');
    }
```

**Edit.vue**

```
 updateSoftware(){
        if (confirm("Do you want to update the software ?")) {
            this.$inertia.put(this.route('software.update',
                {software : this.software_id}), this.form);
        } 
    },
```

**PS:**

**this.form** : contain the data related to v-model

**this.software_id** : contain the **id** of the current instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is likely that you are using the `PUT` method which is not be default supported by HTML forms using a `multipart/form-data` request, I bet you are using `POST` when storing the file which is working.

Try adding using post but adding this `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">` to your form.

Or you can change your update method to:

```
 updateSoftware(){
        if (confirm("Do you want to update the software ?")) {
            this.$inertia.post(this.route('software.update',
                {software : this.software_id,
                 _method: 'put',
                }), this.form);
        } 
    },
```

Check out the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing) on how to spoof the method.

And read [here](https://inertiajs.com/file-uploads) on how to properly upload an image with Inertia.